# EditText horizontal and vertical scroll

Tags: android, android-studio

I create EditText to put long text. So i want this EditText to be able to scroll horizontally and vertically so the inputed text won't be wrapped to the next line when it's width is longer than the EditText. I have tried using android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" and other experiment with EditText properties but didn't found the solution.

[image]

Comment: What do you get right now? And what do you want to change in it?

Comment: Sorry, maybe you can back look to the post :D

Comment: Not sure if you can implement both vertical and horizontal scrolls at the same time. When using `textMultiLine` input type the text is automatically transferred to the next line if it doesn't fit to the current. Thereby, you will have only vertical scroll. On the other hand, if you use `text` input type then you will have only horizontal scroll. Is it enough? Or you have to implement horizontal too?

Comment: Can you show us your xml file ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your xml:

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

and i think EditText scroll automatically

Comment: cannot resolve AN_INTEGER

Comment: @zihadrizkyef replace AN_INTEGER with a number(the maximum number of lines the `EditText` should have).

Comment: i want it to be able to scroll horizontally and vertically :D